# Make Kubernetes cluster search for image in multiple places

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, containers

I want to reference a container image by name and digest only rather than by the full URI.

I have strongly-hashed Kubernetes object spec files that mention docker images.
We have several private container image repos (prod, staging, dev) with multiple sub-directories.

I need a way to be able to specify the docker image "search prefixes" without modifying the Kubernetes object spec files.

Example:
I have a checked-in hashed file with the following line:

`image: something@sha256:2635462354664526623546235645264`

The image is first pushed to `gcr.io/dev-bucket/commit-hash/something`. Then it's copied to `gcr.io/staging-bucket/commit-hash/something` and finally to `gcr.io/prod-bucket/something`.

I'd like to be able to tell Kubernetes possible image search locations/prefixes so that I can use that object file without any changes. (Modifying the files becomes a big problem when they form a strongly-hashed tree.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `imagePullSecrets`.

You should create a `docker-registry` secret with the url and all authentication needed for each of the stages/buckets.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry dev-bucket --docker-server=https://hub.docker.com --docker-username=user --docker-email=user@example.com --docker-password=password
```

Then while creating a `POD` you should do something as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
- name: test-container
  image: <registry_name>/<image_name>:<tagname>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: dev-bucket
```

Please do check the [Google Cloud Registry (GCR) with external Kubernetes](http://docs.heptio.com/content/private-registries/pr-gcr.html) guide, and how to [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Do not forget about creating the service account in gcloud, with permissions to GCR and keys for the service account.

You should add `tags` to your images, that way you will be able to push just one image over to different tag.

EDIT:

Here is an example:

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
d1725b59e92d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0add3ace90ecb4adbf7777e9aacf18357296e799f81cabc9fde470971e499788
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
```

Now we will add new tags to it

```
$ docker tag hello-world gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world:dev_latest
$ docker push gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world:dev_latest
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world]
428c97da766c: Layer already exists
dev_latest: digest: sha256:1a6fd470b9ce10849be79e99529a88371dff60c60aab424c077007f6979b4812 size: 524
$ docker tag hello-world gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world:stage_latest                                                                                                                    
$ docker push gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world:stage_latest                                                                                                                               
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world]
428c97da766c: Layer already exists
stage_latest: digest: sha256:1a6fd470b9ce10849be79e99529a88371dff60c60aab424c077007f6979b4812 size: 524
$ docker tag hello-world gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world:prod_latest                                                                                                                     
$ docker push gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world:prod_latest                                                                                                                                
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/project-for-x/hello-world]
428c97da766c: Layer already exists
prod_latest: digest: sha256:1a6fd470b9ce10849be79e99529a88371dff60c60aab424c077007f6979b4812 size: 524
```

This created a `hello-world` files inside GCR

```
General information
Image type  Docker Manifest, Schema 2
Media type  :application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
Virtual size    :977 B
Uploaded time   :October 24, 2018 at 3:07:49 PM UTC+2
Build ID    :—
Container classification
Digest: sha256:1a6fd470b9ce10849be79e99529a88371dff60c60aab424c077007f6979b4812 
Tags:   dev_latest prod_latest stage_latest 
Repository: hello-world
Project:    project-for-x
```

That way you can have just one `yaml` file to deploy the same image on different environments.

Comment: I've read about `imagePullSecrets` and `myregistrykey`, but I'm not fully sure they will help. I see that in your Pod YAML you have `image: gcr.io/<registry_name>/<image_name>:<tagname>`. This looks like a full image URL. Doesn't it mean that Kubernetes will always pull from `gcr.io/<registry_name>` and never from gcr.io/<staging_registry_name>? I also see that you have `--docker-server=https://gcr.io/dev-bucket/commit-hash/something`. Does this syntax really work? As far as I know, this must point to the Server API endpoint and cannot point to some bucket or subdir.

Comment: I've checked and it's not needed to provide address inside `yaml` file (I've edited my answer), as it's already set inside secret.When you are pushing an image to GCR or Docker Hub, you need to have an account. In GCP it's a `Project ID`, if you will have a separate Project IDs for each env then it will work the way you want it.

Comment: The addresses which you mentioned as example are invalid, they will never exist in reference to Google Cloud Registry as they require `Project ID` and there is no sub paths.

Comment: @Ark-kun I've edited the answer and added examples how to add tags to a existing image, hope that help in you case.